# Write image metadata in C# .Net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, image, metadata

anybody know if it is possible to write meta data to a BitMap class in C#? The constraint is that only .**NET 2.0** can be used.

I read about the PropertyItem class in C# but it does not explain how to set the property; it only showed how to get the property.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here's an example in VB.

```
  Dim prop As PropertyItem
  prop = img.PropertyItems(0) ' no constructor   
  prop.Id = tagNo
  prop.Len = nBytes
  prop.Type = dataType
  prop.Value = bs   
  img.SetPropertyItem(prop)
```

(`img` is an `Image`. `bs` is an array of `byte`.) You do have to save the image into a new file, because .net apparently reads the exif data from the old file instead of keeping it in memory.